# How should resource qualifiers respond?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Following is my directory structure to make my question more understandable.

```
res/
  layout/
    a.xml
    b.xml
  layout-land/
    a.xml
    b.xml
  layout-sw600dp-land/
    a.xml
  layout-sw720dp-land/
    a.xml
```

Now according to my understanding, if a device which fits with the `layout-sw720p-land` qualifier and tries to access `b.xml`, this will be the order `layout-sw720p-land` -> `layout-land` -> `layout` when Dalvik will try to load `b.xml` and it will find the resource in `layout-land` folder and will never go to `layout` folder to load `b.xml`.

This is working fine for the device that I have with me. But I am getting a lot of crash reports on Google Play where this is not happening. And if the device does not find the resource in `layout-sw720p-land`, it is going to `layout` folder and loading `b.xml` instead of loading it from `layout-land.xml`.

What can be the issue here? Is it device specific issue?

Comment: did you do any analytics on devices, which one have most errors? there are a lot of dummy low-quality chinese phones, which may cause a lot of unacceptable crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the os version of device in which the application is failing, it should be >= 3.2 since resource name qualifiers (sw720, etc)are supported for same and above.

Try adding layout-large and layout-xlarge folder with the a.xml and b.xml files.

Check this url http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch